# Ubuntu 22.04 Reverse_poxy error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number

Tags: 22.04, ssl

### 1. The problem I'm having:

Hi people
I need your help with caddy server reverse proxy

For example

Caddy installed on server Ubuntu 22.04 IP- 10.0.0.5

connect 100.100.50.50 via vpn tunnel

and in this server hosts file inputted

```
100.100.50.50 someservice.com
100.100.50.50 someservice2.com
```

In my windows machine
hosts file inputted this IP Ubuntu server

```
10.0.0.5 someservice.com
10.0.0.5 someservice2.com
```

I try post via insomnia and get this error

### 2. Error messages and/or full log output:

```
 * Preparing request to https://someservice.com:9444/oauth2/token
* Current time is 2023-07-06T11:25:18.425Z
* Enable automatic URL encoding
* Using default HTTP version
* Enable SSL validation
* Too old connection (1128 seconds), disconnect it
* Connection 28 seems to be dead!
* Closing connection 28
* Hostname in DNS cache was stale, zapped
* Trying 10.0.0.5:9444...
* Connected to someservice.com (10.0.0.5) port 9444 (#30)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* (5454) (IN), , Unknown (72):
*error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number
* Closing connection 30
```

### 3. Caddy version:

2.6.4 version

#### d. My complete Caddy config:

```
:8243 {
          reverse_proxy 100.100.50.50:8243
         }

:9444 {
        reverse_proxy 100.100.50.50:9444
}
```